# Button Doesn't Work After Second Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a button that calls a function in javascript.  The javascript in turn runs two consecutive ajax calls.  After the first one finishes, it does some extra work, then runs the second ajax call.

The button works upon first clicking it.  However, when I want to click it again the following error pops up...

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

It is in reference to my function that is being called 'onclick' from the button.

I am pretty new to ajax but I'm sure that this shouldn't be happening.  Other buttons are working just fine, and they all call functions from the same script.  It just seems to be this one function.  I would have expected there to be a semicolon missing or something, but then the first time wouldn't have worked...  Also, I do know that the function finished executing, since I debugged the function and it reaches the bottom...

Here are my ajax calls in case you're interested...

```
var $response = $.ajax({
    url: $abs_filename,
    type: 'HEAD',
    async: false,
    success: function () {
        console.log('done');
    }
}).status;
($response != "200") ? $exist = false : $exist = true;
```

....lots of extra code here
....

```
var response = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/SERT/includes/file_operations.php',//url of receiver file on server
    data: {saves: $save_data}, //your data
    dataType: 'text', //text...
    success: function(res) {
        alert(res);
    },
    async: false
}).status;
```

EDIT:
My function is called by

```
<input type="button" .... onclick="save_session()">
```

Comment: I have read other forum posts on a similar situation, but they don't seem to apply to my problem... Also, I did try their solutions and they didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please post the `click` listener binding

Comment: I stopped reading about the time i saw `($response != "200") ? $exist = false : $exist = true;`.

Comment: I love "doesn't work" titled questions

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado The whole function that is called when the button is clicked?  I have the binding in the HTML, onclick="save_session()"

Answer (score 0):

You've not actually shown the code that is causing the error.

However...

Don't do this; it doesn't do what you think it does.

```
($response != "200") ? $exist = false : $exist = true;
```

Do this:

```
$exist = $response == "200";
```

And just **DON'T** use synchronous XHR.

Comment: Looks like it ought to be equals, not not-equals.  :P

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out...

So I had a jQuery append operation going on inside of the save_session() function.  This operation was as such...

```
$bottom_section.append('<input type="hidden" name="save_session" value="' + $total + ' ' + $paragraph + '">');
```

When I took this out then the whole thing worked as expected.  My guess is that by naming the input "save_session" messed with the function definition of save_session() in memory.  Now there wasn't a definition conflict, then it was okay.